# How to wrap every submenu item in a div tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

so I wanted to know how, if at all, you could wrap every `<li>` tag of a wordpress submenu, under a `<div>` tag, such that the output looks something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">


  <ul class="sub-menu ">
    <div class="something"><li class="menu-item"></li></div>
    <div class="something"><li class="menu-item"></li></div>
  </ul>

</ul>
```

I'm new to wordpress so I don't know much about it, I've tried using a Walker but that just wraps around the `<ul>` tag, whereas I want to wrap every single `<li>` tag, I don't even know if it's possible, so feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help, my working walker with bootstrap 5:

```
class My_Walker_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

private $curr_item = null;
private $count     = 0;

public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL ) {
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); 
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); 
    
    $is_parent    = get_post_meta( $this->curr_item->db_id, '_featured_menu_meta', true );
    $is_parent    = rest_sanitize_boolean( $is_parent );
    $menu_parents = get_option('featured_menu_parents', []);
    $is_featured  = in_array( $this->curr_item->menu_item_parent, $menu_parents);
    
    $class_names = ( $display_depth >= 1 ? 'dropdown-menu' : '' );
    $class_names = ($is_parent || $is_featured) && $display_depth == 1 ? 'list-unstyled mb-0' : $class_names;

    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}

public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $this->curr_item = $data_object;

    $item         = $data_object;
    $indent       = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); 
    $has_children = $args->walker->has_children;
    $is_parent    = get_post_meta( $item->db_id, '_featured_menu_meta', true );
    $is_parent    = rest_sanitize_boolean( $is_parent );
    $menu_parents = get_option('featured_menu_parents', []);
    $is_featured  = in_array($item->menu_item_parent, $menu_parents);
    
    // menu_item_parent
    if ( $depth == 0 ) {
        $item_class = $has_children ? 'nav-item dropdown' : 'nav-item';
    }

    if ( $depth >= 1 ) {
        $item_class = $has_children ? 'dropdown' : '';
    }       

    $item_attr = $item_class ? ' class="'. $item_class . '"' : '';
    $output   .= $indent . '<li'. $item_attr . '>';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= $has_children && $depth == 0 ? ' data-bs-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

    if( $item->current ) {
        $attr_classes = ' class="nav-link active' . ( $has_children ? ' dropdown-toggle' : '' ) . '"';
    } else {
        $attr_classes = ' class="nav-link'. ( $has_children ? ' dropdown-toggle' : '' ) . '"';
    }

    if ( $is_parent && $depth == 0 ) {
        $args->after  = '<div class="dropdown-menu overflow-hidden p-0" data-bs-popper="static">';
        $args->after .= '<div class="d-lg-flex">';
        $args->after .= '<div class="mega-dropdown-column pt-1 pt-lg-3 pb-lg-4">';
    } 
    
    if ( $is_featured && $depth == 1 ) {
        $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $item->object_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
        $thumb_url = trim($thumb_url);
        $visibile  = $this->count == 1 ? ' rounded-3 rounded-start-0' : ' zindex-2 opacity-0';

        if( $thumb_url ) {
            $args->after = '<span class="mega-dropdown-column position-absolute top-0 end-0 h-100 bg-size-cover bg-repeat-0'.$visibile.'" style="background-image: url('.$thumb_url .');">';
        }

        $attr_classes = ' class="dropdown-item"';
    } 

    $attributes .= $attr_classes;

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
        $args->before,
        $attributes,
        $args->link_before,
        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
        $args->link_after,
        $args->after
    );

    $args->after  = '';
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    $this->count++;
}

public function end_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $item         = $data_object;
    $is_parent    = get_post_meta( $item->db_id, '_featured_menu_meta', true );
    $is_parent    = rest_sanitize_boolean( $is_parent );
    $menu_parents = get_option('featured_menu_parents', []);
    $is_featured  = in_array($item->menu_item_parent, $menu_parents);

    if ( $is_parent && 0 == $depth ) {
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= ' <div class="mega-dropdown-column position-relative border-start zindex-3"></div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    if ( $is_featured && $depth == 1 ) {
        $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $item->object_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
        $thumb_url = trim($thumb_url);

        if( $thumb_url ) {
            $output .= '</span>';
        }
    } 
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
```

}

```
wp_nav_menu([
                'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
                'container'       => 'nav',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'    => 'navbarNav',
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav navbar-nav-scroll me-auto',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 3,
                'walker'          => new My_Walker_Menu()

            ]);
```

Comment: Created for this site: https://around.createx.studio/index.html  - menu if you interested in,  You can take their site html try to recreate for understanding of the code